# Getting total number of viewers of an specific activity

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to get the total number of viewers of an activity in an android app? I searched, but the only thing I found was `Google Analytics`. but as far as I got, this API only shows the number of install uninstalls and some other features not the one that I want.
Appreciate your answers

Comment: What do you mean by "viewers"? Number of View components inside activity's layout? Are you going to check Activity from another app?

Comment: @Loop no I meant how many times users viewed an specific activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need.

> Integrate Flurry Analytics in five minutes to get basic insights into
>   your users and app performance, or set up advanced analysis of complex
>   events to get a deep understanding of everything your users are doing.
>   From initial launch to the top of the charts, Flurry Analytics is free
>   at any scale and available for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows
>   Phone, and mobile web.

For more info:http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you are trying to find how many users have visited an Activity in your app. The Google Analytics does give you that details. You can check the implementation here :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens#implementation